# How to use Circle image View in Roku..?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am using BrightScript and SceneGraph components to display an image in a circle view but Circle View option is not found. I want a view like the image below:

[image: example]

Comment: which way you use to display an image 1.directly you use image link. or 2. you retrieve an image from XML

Comment: using both way but image Display in rectangle view.. i want circular view

Comment: Try with MaskGroup answer is already given below.

Comment: ok i will try....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to insert your `Poster` node in a [MaskGroup](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/control-nodes/maskgroup.md) and then set a circular mask image to your mask group using the property `maskUri`.

Check out Roku's `MaskGroup` example on [GitHub](https://github.com/rokudev/samples/tree/master/ux%20components/control/MaskGroupExample).

Keep in mind that the mask image needs to be solid black in order to achieve the effect that you want, for example:
[image]

Comment: @SumitGhorpade - A `MaskGroup` is the only way to achieve a "Circular View" on Roku.